# Pass data from Django template to react App

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app using Django - DRF - React through template component invocation. Question is: Whats the right way to pass data from django view-template to react app-component, for example, if the api called in app fetch method used a dynamic parameter:

`fetch("/api/endpoint`") to `fetch("/api/endpoint/modelPrimaryKey`")

Sources used:

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

index.html

```
...
</body>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
</html>
```

main.js (compiled by webpack from this source)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loaded: false,
      placeholder: "Loading"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/endpoint")
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status > 400) {
          return this.setState(() => {
            return { placeholder: "Something went wrong!" };
          });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState(() => {
          return {
            data,
            loaded: true
          };
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ... some jsx
    );
  }
}

export default App;
const container = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, container);
```